# Using malloc for allocation of multi-dimensional arrays with different row lengths

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I have the following `C` code :

```
int *a;
size_t size = 2000*sizeof(int);
a = malloc(size);
```

which works fine. But if I have the following :

```
char **b = malloc(2000*sizeof *b);
```

where every element of `b` has different length.

How is it possible to do the same thing for `b` as i did for `a`; i.e. the following code would hold correct?

```
char *c;
size_t size = 2000*sizeof(char *);
c = malloc(size);
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

First, you need to allocate array of pointers like `char **c = malloc( N * sizeof( char* ))`, then allocate each row with a separate call to `malloc`, probably in the loop:

```
/* N is the number of rows  */
/* note: c is char** */
if (( c = malloc( N*sizeof( char* ))) == NULL )
{ /* error */ }

for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
  /* x_i here is the size of given row, no need to
   * multiply by sizeof( char ), it's always 1
   */
  if (( c[i] = malloc( x_i )) == NULL )
  { /* error */ }

  /* probably init the row here */
}

/* access matrix elements: c[i] give you a pointer
 * to the row array, c[i][j] indexes an element
 */
c[i][j] = 'a';
```

If you know the total number of elements (e.g. `N*M`) you can do this in a single allocation.

Comment: If you alloc N*M bytes in a single operation, then you fill all the c[i]s manually: c[i] = p + M*i;

Comment: That depends on the c's type - if it's char**, then yes, if it's char*, then the indexing changes: element[i][j] ~ c[i*M + j].

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov, there are a lot of mallocs in the code, how can this be all freed? by also using for loops?

Comment: @e19293001 yes, one `free` for each `malloc`. You would have to loop through the `char*` variables freeing them, and then free the `char**`.

Comment: I saw the same in a book, it said "...memory is not guaranteed to be contiguous."?

Answer (score 49):

The typical form for dynamically allocating an NxM array of type T is

```
T **a = malloc(sizeof *a * N);
if (a)
{
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    a[i] = malloc(sizeof *a[i] * M);
  }
}
```

If each element of the array has a different length, then replace M with the appropriate length for that element; for example

```
T **a = malloc(sizeof *a * N);
if (a)
{
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    a[i] = malloc(sizeof *a[i] * length_for_this_element);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I have the total number of int's that I'm gonna have, but not how many of those go into each array, how should I proceed?

Comment: Very clear answer, thank you! Could you also add a description of in which order to properly `free` the allocated memory?

Comment: @Kagaratsch: In general, free in the reverse order you allocated - that is, free each `a[i]` first, then free `a`.

Answer (score 29):

Equivalent memory allocation for `char a[10][20]` would be as follows.

```
char **a;

a=malloc(10*sizeof(char *));

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    a[i]=malloc(20*sizeof(char));
```

I hope this looks simple to understand.

Answer (score 10):

The other approach would be to allocate one contiguous chunk of memory comprising header block for pointers to rows as well as body block to store actual data in rows. Then just mark up memory by assigning addresses of memory in body to the pointers in header on per-row basis. It would look like follows:

```
int** 2dAlloc(int rows, int* columns) {    
    int header = rows * sizeof(int*);

    int body = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<rows; body+=columnSizes[i++]) {  
    }
    body*=sizeof(int);

    int** rowptr = (int**)malloc(header + body);

    int* buf  = (int*)(rowptr + rows);
    rowptr[0] = buf;
    int k;
    for(k = 1; k < rows; ++k) {
        rowptr[k] = rowptr[k-1] + columns[k-1];
    }
    return rowptr;
}

int main() {
    // specifying column amount on per-row basis
    int columns[] = {1,2,3};
    int rows = sizeof(columns)/sizeof(int);
    int** matrix = 2dAlloc(rows, &columns);

    // using allocated array
    for(int i = 0; i<rows; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j<columns[i]; ++j) {
            cout<<matrix[i][j]<<", ";
        }   
            cout<<endl;
    }

    // now it is time to get rid of allocated 
    // memory in only one call to "free"
    free matrix;
}
```

The advantage of this approach is elegant freeing of memory and ability to use array-like notation to access elements of the resulting 2D array.

Comment: Something to note: this solution will generally perform better with respect to cache coherency, as the individual rows are guaranteed to be contiguous, unlike in the other approaches that allocate one row at a time, and may lead to a matrix whose component parts are scattered throughout a highly fragmented heap.

Comment: This unfortunately also has the side-effect of not guaranteeing alignment for non-pointer-sized types. Ex: a system with 32-bit pointers and 64bit doubles with an odd number of rows will start the first column of row of doubles on an unaligned boundary for `double`. It is *very* important this is accounted for, as it can easily lead to a bus error due to improper data alignment. A general solution should ensure the data-rows start on an 8-byte boundary, making additional allocation space and adjusting accordingly when assigning row pointers to the primary pointer segment.

Comment: @DmitryAleks : Where are you declaring`columnSizes[]`?

Answer (score 3):

If every element in b has different lengths, then you need to do something like:

```
int totalLength = 0;
for_every_element_in_b {
    totalLength += length_of_this_b_in_bytes;
}
return malloc(totalLength);
```

Comment: It doesn't allocate memory for a 1-dimensional array of char* pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I think a 2 step approach is best, because c 2-d arrays are just and array of arrays.  The first step is to allocate a single array, then loop through it allocating arrays for each column as you go.  [This article](http://www.eumus.edu.uy/eme/c/c-notes_summit/intermediate/sx9.html) gives good detail.

Answer (score 1):

2-D Array Dynamic Memory Allocation

```
int **a,i;

// for any number of rows & columns this will work
a = malloc(rows*sizeof(int *));
for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    *(a+i) = malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

malloc does not allocate on specific boundaries, so it must be assumed that it allocates on a byte boundary.

The returned pointer can then not be used if converted to any other type, since accessing that pointer will probably produce a memory access violation by the CPU, and the application will be immediately shut down.