# An array that represents a panel with filled and blank spaces

Tags: c, arrays, flood-fill

I am making a program that would read the input (the coordinates of horizontal and vertical lines) like this:

```
struct Data {
    // the beginning and ending coordinate of a line
    int xStart;
    int xEnd;
    int yStart;
    int yEnd;
};
// the dimension of panel on which you draw lines
int panelWidth, panelHeight;
// number of lines drawn on the panel
int numLines;

scanf("%d %d", &panelWidth, &panelHeight);
struct Data data[5];
int j;
int i;

j = 0;
if (scanf("%s", &numLines) == 1)
 {
    for (i = 0 ; ((i < numLines) && (j < 5)) ; ++i)
     {
        if (scanf("%d %d %d %d",
            &data[j].xStart, 
            &data[j].yStart, 
            &data[j].xEnd, 
            &data[j].yEnd) == 4)
         {
            j++;
         }
     }
 }
```

Now I would like to put these values in an array that would represent the panel and draw all the lines on the panel (e.g. put the value 1 where there is a line and 0 where the cells are empty), so that I can then count all the zones that these lines make (spaces with zeros).

It should work like flood fill.

How do I make such array? Or is there a better option?

> This is an example of a more complicated input:

```
27 27 // width, height
7 // number of Lines
10 0 10 10 // xStart, xEnd, yStart, yEnd
0 10 10 10 // xStart, xEnd ...
5 5 15 5
15 5 15 15
5 15 21 15
5 5 5 15
5 20 26 20
```

Comment: Is your question correctly condensed to 'how do I make an array of a certain size in C'?

Comment: Scratching head..., why read the information into a struct if you really want it in an array? Or, are you talking about creating an array of size `(xmax-xmin) X (ymax-ymin)`?

Comment: Well kind of, what I had in mind was to make an array or something that would represent a net with cells, something like a coordinate system in which you would draw lines that would divide the coordinate system (more of a panel of cells) into more zones, And if it was an array it would fill the cells where the lines are with 1 and the rest with 0, so that you can then read the number of zones with flood-fill. My question is if you can make such an array and how?

Comment: Well, yes, you can, you can do anything in C, it is just a matter of what it takes. I understand your flood-fill of 1/0 for lines, etc.. Can you give an example of what the data would look like? Are we talking a simple cross or diagonals?

Comment: like if you had the pane of siz 50x50 and 2 lines drawn on it with coordinates for the first line: xStart = 0, xEnd = 15 yStart = 49, yEnd=15;  and the second line: xStart = 10, xEnd = 0 yStart = 10, yEnd=49;  and the answer would be 4, because these are a vertical and horizontal line that split the panel in four zones

Comment: the lines would be horizontal and vertical (no diagonal ones) and they could be situated anywhere in the panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is your question correctly condensed to 'how do I make an array of a certain size in C'?
>
> –  Jongware

I'm guessing that Jongware is on to something, and that you are trying to dynamically allocate an n x m array. In other words, you're hoping to make an array that has its size determined by what the user types in.

To do this, you have to use 'the heap'. If you haven't done dynamic memory allocation in C before, I recommend just making a large array (say 10,000 elements) and only using whatever you need. Then you can just make sure the user can't enter anything that would be bigger than that.

If you really want to do it dynamically, we'll be using your `panelWidth` and `panelHeight` variables. In fact, there is a nice post on this right over here on StackOverflow:

[Malloc a 2d array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677566/malloc-a-2d-array-in-c)

Hopefully one of those methods is what you're looking for. If not, it wouldn't hurt to clarify what exactly you're asking. You gave lots of information, but not everything is really relevant. I think Jongware has summarized your question well.