# Unable to Create a 2d data structure of array size [300][300]-->Stack Overflow

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I want to create 2d datastructure of [300][300], but I am getting stack overflow error.

Here is how I have defined,

```
typedef struct DST
{
    float salary;
    float x1;
    float x2;
};

struct DST person[300][300];
```

I am getting an error for the above declaration.

but, if I declare `struct DST person[300][70];` --> this is working fine

So, it is a memory handling issue, I am unable to solve it.

Software: Visual Studio 2010

Could anybody please help me out with this?

Comment: You could try increasing the size of your stack, or you could always create the array dynamically

Comment: You have a limited space on the stack. You'll have to allocate memory dynamically to be able to use such large arrays of your struct.

Comment: Are you defining that `person` variable into a function? If not, your stack overflow may come from an entirely different place ...

Comment: std::vector<std::vector<DST>> person;

Comment: Are we talking [c] or [c++]? They have different answers.

Comment: This typedef is pointless, since you don't provide the alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you typedef the struct you don't need to use the struct keyword when initializing it, but you need to give it a name. It should look something like this:

```
typedef struct DST
{
    float salary;
    float x1;
    float x2;
} DST;

DST person[300][300];
```

Also since you're not allocating it using malloc it's being allocated on the stack, so as soon as you leave the function you declare it in you won't be able to access it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Structure `DST` contains [`12B`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx) of data. When [memory alignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx) is turned on (and set to its [default value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh3e3fd0.aspx) - `8B`) it takes `16B` for each instance.

```
300*300*16B = 1440000B = ~1.4MB
```

Local variable declared like this [get allocated on the stack](http://www.gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html#sec-4-1) and since [the default stack size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx) for Visual Studio is `1MB`, the error is appropriate.

To fix this you can either increase the stack size [`/F 2000000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx) (*I don't think it's good practice to set up larger stack*), or rather allocate memory on the heap using:

- [*std::containers*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) (`std::vector<std::vector<DST>>` would do)
- [`new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)
- [`malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970698/using-malloc-for-allocation-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-with-different-row-lengt) (C)
- *one of the [WinAPI allocation methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366533(v=vs.85).aspx)* (C)

Answer (score 2):

300 * 300 * 12 bytes makes just over 1MB. Which is a VERY large set to put on the stack.

The simple solution in C++ is to use `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<DST>> person(300);
for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) 
  person[i].resize(300);
```

This avoids direct usage of `new` (and then needing to use `delete` later).

If you have a C++11 compiler, you could do:

```
std::vector<std::array<DST, 300>> person;
```

and thus avoid the loop to resize.

Note that although it's possible to "ask for a bigger stack", that should not really be used to allocate single large data structures on the stack. Larger stack is NECESSARY when you have lots of call levels, each of which have small amounts of data on the stack. Anything much larger than 1KB should make you think "Should this really go on the stack, or should I do something else".

Comment: I like this one better because containers! Not as clumsy as a pointer. An elegant weapon, for a more civilized age.

Comment: I don`t like it because of `vector<vector>`. `vector<array>` would be much better. @ftwl: I would call the `resize` loop clumsy.

Comment: @nwp: That REQUIRES C++11, but does get rid of the loop.

Comment: How about array<array> ? Both dimensions are known.

Comment: @quentin: That doesn't solve anything in the original question, as `std::array` is just a nice wrapper to produce a `[]` style array, with some inline functions to make it look similar to a `std::vector` and other containers (`std::array` has `size`, `begin`, `end` etc)

Comment: Definitely the correct structure when you have all the dimensions though. Throw in a `unique_ptr` to allocate it dynamically and you're good to go, no resizing to do, no fears about reallocation.

Answer (score 0):

*This is **the** question to ask on stackoverflow.*

Together with the two solutions mentioned in other answers - allocating the array on heap or increasing stack size, there is a third one.

If you define the array `static` or in global scope, it will be created in the program data segment.

For simple proof of concept programs this may the simplest solution. 
Also, it may generate fastest code on some (old, simple) compilers.

In general, this is not good style.

Just cut and paste your definion from a funciton definition to file scope....

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all. :)

To be honest, I am very poor at memory operations. Looking into various possible solutions I realized I am yet to learn a lot.

These answers have solved my issue.

Multiple possible solutions were suggested.

Currently I have used: using std::vector

```
std::vector<std::vector<DST>> person(300);
for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) 
person[i].resize(300);
```

This is working absolutely fine.

I will explore on all other solutions and work on it.
Thank You