# how to malloc() a multidimensional array of non-default type?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, malloc

I have the following array describing a game board:

```
square * board = (square *)malloc(sizeof(square)*n*n);
```

How can I initalize such an array with its elements pointing to further game boards of the above declaration?

That is, I want to initialize slices of the overall `board` array; like so (pseudocode):

```
boards[0] -> [0,0,...0]
boards[1] -> [0,0,...0]
boards[2] -> [0,0,...0]
```

I must use `malloc()` to allocate the boards array.

I have already tried this way:

```
square (*t_board)[11]; 
t_board = malloc(sizeof(player)*n*n*11);
```

But I got the error: "use of undeclared indentifier 't_board'; did you mean 'board'?"

Comment: That's nice.  Did you have a question?

Comment: thanks for the editing, please post an anwser if you have one

Comment: similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970698/using-malloc-for-allocation-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-with-different-row-lengt

Comment: @AmitSharma, I have seen it, it did not help though

Comment: What does "non-default type" mean?

Comment: @gen Why didn't that help?  Also: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First allocate memory for the array with pointers and then the boards.

```
square **boards;
int nbr_boards = 5;
int n = 24;

//Allocate space for pointers
boards = malloc(nbr_boards * sizeof *boards);

//Allocate space for each board
for (int i = 0; i < nbr_boards; ++i)
        boards[i] = malloc(n * n sizeof **boards);
```

You can use this as

```
boards[BOARD_INDEX][SQUARE_INDEX]
```

To later free it you have to loop through the pointers again:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbr_boards; ++i)
        free(boards[i]);
free(boards);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the type, allocating a `N`x`N` array takes one of the following forms:

If `N` is known at compile time, or if variable-length arrays are supported, it's easy:

```
T (*arr)[N] = malloc( sizeof *arr * N );
```

Elements are accessed as `arr[i][j]`.  When you're done, you'd free them as

```
free( arr );
```

If `N` is not known at compile time and VLAs are not supported *and* all array elements must be contiguous, then you'd need to allocate a 1D array and compute the offset:

```
T *arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * N * N );
...
x = arr[ i * N + j ];
```

If the array elements don't have to be contiguous, you can do a piecewise allocation:

```
T *arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * N );
if ( arr )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
  {
    arr[i] = malloc( sizeof *arr[i] * N );
  }
}
```

You'd access this array as `arr[i][j]`, but since you allocated it piecewise, you must free it the same way:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
  free( arr[i] );
free( arr );
```

If you want to initialize your array elements to all-bits-0, use `calloc` instead of `malloc`:

```
T (*arr)[N] = calloc( N, sizeof *arr );
```

If you want to initialize your array elements to something other than all-bits-zero, then that depends on what `T` looks like.  If `T` is, say, a structure type containing two integer elements, and you're using a C99 or later compiler, you could use a *compound literal* combined with `memcpy`:

```
memcpy( arr[i], ( struct foo [] ){ {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8} ... } );
```

Comment: +1 Wrote the answer I would have - saved me time.  Minor style idea: maybe `malloc( N * sizeof *arr )` vs. `malloc( sizeof *arr * N )` as it matches `nmemb, size` order of `calloc( N, sizeof *arr )`.  Of course the same allocation results with `malloc()` regardless of how the product is formed.