# How to create matrix, by reading the length in an input file

Tags: c, file, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix, `int matrix1[size][size]`, but I have to read the length from the first line of a file.

I can read read from the file with no problem, but then when I try to declare the matrix with the variable given to me by the file there's always a compiling error.

How can I get around this?

Sorry about the English

Edited Code:

```
int num;

FILE *fp;

fp = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;
if( fp == NULL) {
    perror(argv[1]); 
    return -1;
}

fscanf(fp,"%d", &num);

int matriz[num][num];
```

Error message is warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘matriz’

Comment: can you change(or add) compile option to `-std=c99`?

Comment: Tried [`malloc()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/malloc/) yet ?

Comment: @Alexbot11 If it is not C99 or later can not be such a description. You need to be implemented using malloc.

Comment: i dont have a lot of experience with malloc(); but i guess its time to learn it, since it does seem to be the  only way, thank you for the anwsers

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970698/using-malloc-for-allocation-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-with-different-row-lengt