# Declare array insde a structure in c

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

Hi i would like declare a array of size x, this size will be know at runtime (not a static declatrion). how to do that. An efficient way to do that.

I had structure like this

```
    #define SIZE 50
    struct abc {
                  int students[SIZE];
                  int age;
   }
```

i would like read SIZE from some point at run time, instead of predefining it.

Edit : can we allocate memory for entire structure including array dynamically.

```
        strcut abc {
                     int *students; // should point to array of SIZE.
                     int age;
       }s;
```

can we get sizeof struct = size of entire struct(including array); ?

Answer (score 5):

If the size is known at runtime, you need to use dynamic allocation.

```
struct abc 
{
  int *students;
  int age;
}
```

Then in code,

```
struct abc var;
var.students = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
```

and at the end of your code

```
free(var.students);
```

Comment: how to handle 2d array, say arry[SIZE] [FIX] ?

Comment: see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970698/using-malloc-for-allocation-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-with-different-row-lengt)

Comment: second index is predefined, in this can plz provide example. for this use case.

Comment: In this case also you need to use a 2D array and malloc it as shown in the above link. Only thing is that FIX will be a constant.

Answer (score 1):

There are two maybe simpler solution possible. You can use a empty sized array at the end of the `struct`:

```
struct abc {
    int age;
    int students[];
};

unsigned count = 10;
struct abc* foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo) + (count * sizeof(foo->students[0])));
```

Here you need only one `malloc()` call if you want both, the `struct` and the `array` being allocated dynamically. And also only one free. For a 2d array you have to alloc it as a 1d array and calculate the indices for your own.

An other solution could be:

```
unsigned count = 10;
struct abcd {
    int age;
    int students[count];
};
```

Simple use a variable length array in the `struct` direct. Here you can use 2d as usual.

Comment: Hey thannks,  how can we declare a pointer for array inside struct, then allocate memory for enitre struct including array ?