# C: Sort long list that can't fit into arrays

Tags: c, file, sorting

I have a 80370-long list of 30-digit numbers in a text file, each in a separate line.
I want to sort them in C.

My idea was creating a new file, then adding the first number to it.
Then, each time we compare it with another number. If it's smaller, the other number is appended. Easy. However, if it's larger, the new number must be prepended.
I tried prepending like so:

```
void prepend(char line[], FILE* w, FILE* waux, char filename[], char auxname[]) {
    fprintf(waux, "%s\n", line); //print new number to new file (waux)
    char ch;
    while((ch = fgetc(w)) != EOF) {
        fputc(ch, waux); //read old file (w) and add to new file (waux)
    }
    remove(filename); //delete old file
    rename(auxname, filename); //rename new file to old file's name
}
```

But then I try to read the output and it's filled with NULL chars (in Notepad++).
Among the million NULL chars we can find the numbers, but they're not sorted at all.

Comment: why do you want to do it by writing partial output to a file? Just read all data, sort and write all data at once. Actually you don't even need to roll your own sorting function, you can use `<stdlib.h>` `qsort` function: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort

Comment: That's a bit more than two megabyte (if you use pointers, perhaps 3MB). It can't be too hard to allocate (using malloc()) an array that can contain so many numbers.

Comment: Alright, I realized that my idea will not work to sort my numbers, so please just consider the problem of the prepending not working. Though, if you have ideas for how to sort them, that would be great. (:

Comment: As mentioned above: read everything into dynamically allocated array, then use qsort to sort it.

Comment: Read all the numbers into an array, sort the array with `qsort`, write the array to the output file.

Comment: 80370 30-digit numbers is not too big for an array on a modern general-purpose computer, even if the numbers are represented as strings of digits.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I didn't think that finding 2mb in the memory was such an easy task. It's great to hear

Comment: File-based sorting used to be a thing, but its importance has greatly diminished with the increase in computers' memory sizes.  It's still important in databases, though.  Efficient implementations are non-trivial.

Comment: even if you are using 32 bit version of windows, you have at least 2 GB of virtual address space. Even if you don't have enough physical RAM let the OS solve this problem for you using swap space. But in you case 2MB is not a bottleneck nowadays

Comment: The array can be a global variable, a static variable, or dynamically allocated with `malloc`. The only thing you *can't* do is declare the array as a local variable.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest: read the whole file in to an array in memory, then use an existing sorting algorithm like `qsort()`

Comment: So I want a 2D array of size `[80370][30]`. How do I do that in `malloc`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970698/using-malloc-for-allocation-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-with-different-row-lengt

Comment: struct tagMyArray { char line[30]; }; struct tagMyArray * myArray = malloc( sizeof( struct tagMyArray ) * 80370);  If( !myArray ) { // handle error }

Comment: Or just `char (*myarr)[30] = malloc (80370 * sizeof *myarr);`

Comment: The basic mechanics of an external sort where the data _is_ too big to fit in memory are: (1) Read as much data into memory as will fit; (2) sort it; (3) write it out to disk; (4) Repeat steps 1-3 until there's no more data to read; (5) merge the sorted files into sorted output files (if necessary, you may have to make multiple merge passes).  The tricks are then optimizing this processing to minimize the amount of data written to disk, and the number of passes over the data in general.

Comment: I had an assembly language assignment (in the mid 90s) that asked us to do this using no extra memory, only registers on a 486 and the file had to be sorted in place.  Needless to say it takes a long time to bubble sort a file 2 lines at a time while swapping 2 characters at a time, especially when the file is on a floppy disk, but it can be done.  Though ~half the class dropped after that assignment.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with the comments that you should allocate memory for all your data using `malloc`, sort the data in memory, and then write the data to the file, I also think that your approach should also work.

I'm guessing that the reason for your approach not working is that you have open file handles to the files at the time you are using

```
remove(filename); //delete old file
rename(auxname, filename); //rename new file to old file's name
```

My suggestion:

1. Open the files in the function.
2. Do the read and append.
3. Close the files.
4. Then do the remove and rename.

---

```
void prepend(char line[], char filename[], char auxname[]) {

   FILE* w = fopen(filename, "r");
   if ( w == NULL )
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s for reading from.\n", filename);
      return;
   }

   FILE* waux = fopen(auxname, "w");
   if ( waux == NULL )
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s for writing to.\n", auxname);
      fclose(w);
      return;
   }

   fprintf(waux, "%s\n", line); //print new number to new file (waux)
   int ch;
   while((ch = fgetc(w)) != EOF) {
      fputc(ch, waux); //read old file (w) and add to new file (waux)
   }

   fclose(waux);
   fclose(w);

   remove(filename); //delete old file
   rename(auxname, filename); //rename new file to old file's name
}
```