# Problems with pointers and 2D - arrays (dynamic allocation of memory)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm new to pointers and I'm trying to implement a simple code, in which I read and write a 2D array, yet I have no idea why this isn't working. Would anyone provide any suggestions?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int read_matr(int ***m, FILE *f){
    int i,j,length,a;
    fscanf(f,"%d",&length);
    *m = (int **)malloc(length*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<length;++i)
        for(j=0;j<length;++j){
                fscanf(f,"%d",&a);
                *(*(m+i)+j) = a;
        }
    return length;
}

void write_matr(int *m[][3], int length, FILE *g){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<length;++i){
        for(j=0;j<length;++j)
            fprintf(g,"%d ",*(*(m+i)+j));
        fprintf(g,"\n");
    }
    fprintf(g,"\n");
}

int main(){
    FILE *f = fopen("datein.txt","r");
    FILE *g = fopen("dateout.txt","w");
    int **m, n = read_matr(m,f);
    write_matr(m,n,g);
    free(m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? What is the expected behaviour? What behaviour do you get vs. expected behaviour?

Comment: Ah yes, the daily three star programming, with the mandatory answers by other three star programmers. I think I'm gonna write a FAQ community wiki about how to do this proper, because very few C programmers seem to know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems with the provided code. :

- You are passing a **int variable as first parameter of read_matr, but this function is requesting a ***int parameter (a pointer to a 2dimensional array). The parameter seems correct, but then you need to pass a pointer to your array in this way:

  ```
  int n = read_matr(&m, f);
  ```
- Your array is supposed to be 2d dimensional, but you are only allocating it as a 1dimensional array. After allocating a first array, you need to allocate each row independently:

  ```
  *m = (int **) malloc(length * sizeof(int*));
  for(i=0; i<length; ++i) {
      (*m)[i] = (int*) malloc(length * sizeof(int));
      ...
  }
  ```

Optionally, you can make a 1dimensionnal array of size length*length, and then you would access `m[i][j] by m[i * length + j]`

Warnings could have helped you a great deal there.

Comment: This is not a 2D array. It is a fragmented look-up table.

Comment: add a `{` in the outer `for` loop or the code will fail.

Answer (score 2):

To correctly allocate a 2D array in modern C, you do like this:

```
int (*array)[x][y] = malloc( sizeof(int[x][y]) );
```

which could be simplified for convenience as:

```
int (*array)[y] = malloc( sizeof(int[x][y]) );
```

To correctly allocate a 2D array in ancient versions of C (C90/ANSI-C), you would use "mangled arrays":

```
int* array = malloc(x*y*z*sizeof(int));
```

---

The above are the *only* ways to dynamically allocate a true 2D array in C. Anything based on pointer-to-pointers is not a 2D array, nor can it be used as one. This is because such pointer-to-pointer "things" are scattered all over the heap. They are slow and needlessly complex.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should look at the compiler warnings. There are a lot in this code. With the help of these you should be able to solve some things on your own.

What i don't get. You define `int **m` and give it uninitialized to the function `read_matr(int ***m, FILE *f)` but what you need to to in that case would be `read_matr(&m, f);`

**EDIT**

So here are just some mistakes you made.

1. Please do **not** cast the pointer malloc returns.

   ```
   int **m;
   *m = malloc(length*sizeof(int));
   ```

Be aware, that what you get is a pointer to a pointer to allocated memory. This is not equal to `m[][]`. If you want to allocate a 2D array your way you should do something like this:

```
int **m;
int rows, cols;
*m = malloc(sizeof(rows) * rows);
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    m[i] = malloc(sizeof(cols) * cols);
}
```

See: [Using malloc for allocation of multi-dimensional arrays with different row lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970698/using-malloc-for-allocation-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-with-different-row-lengt)

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to separate memory management from I/O.  First create your matrix, and once you've verified that succeeded, *then* read your input.

My second suggestion would be to use regular subscript notation (`m[i][j]`) instead of explicit pointer dereferences (`*(*(m + i) + j)`).  Easier to read, harder to get wrong.

Finally, when you allocate memory this way, you have to allocate memory for *each row* individually:

```
void createMatrix( int ***m, size_t length )
{
  *m = malloc( sizeof **m * length );
  if ( !*m )
  {
    // memory allocation error, bail out here
    return;
  }

  size_t i;
  for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ )
  {
    /**
     * Postfix [] has higher precedence than unary *, so *m[i] will be
     * parsed as *(m[i]) - it will index into m and dereference the result.
     * That's not what we want here - we want to index into what m 
     * *points to*, so we have to explicitly group the unary * operator
     * with m and index into the result.
     */
    (*m)[i] = malloc( sizeof *(*m)[i] * length );
    if ( !(*m)[i] )                              
      break;
  }

  if ( i < length )
  {
    // memory allocation failed midway through allocating the rows;
    // free all previously allocated memory before bailing out
    while ( i-- )
      free( (*m)[i] );
    free( *m );
    *m = NULL;
  }
}
```

Assuming you called it as

```
int **m;
createMatrix( &m, 3 ); // note & operator on m
```

you wind up with something that looks like this:

```
     +---+                                                  +---+
m[0] |   | ---------------------------------------> m[0][0] |   |
     +---+                                +---+             +---+
m[1] |   | ---------------------> m[1][0] |   |     m[0][1] |   |
     +---+               +---+            +---+             +---+
m[2] |   | ----> m[2][0] |   |    m[1][1] |   |     m[0][2] |   |
     +---+               +---+            +---+             +---+
      ...        m[2][1] |   |    m[1][2] |   |              ...
                         +---+            +---+
                 m[2][2] |   |             ...
                         +---+
                          ...
```

This is not a true 2D array - the rows are not contiguous.  The element immediately following `m[0][2]` is *not* `m[1][0]`.  You can index it *as though* it were a 2D array, but that's about it.

Sometimes that's not the wrong answer. Depending on how fragmented your heap is, a single `N`x`M` allocation request may fail, but `N` separate allocations of `M` may succeed.  If your algorithm doesn't rely on all elements being contiguous then this will work, although it will likely be slower than using a true `N`x`M` array.

If you want a true, contiguous 2D array whose dimensions are not known until runtime, then you will need a compiler that supports variable-length arrays (VLAs), and you would allocate it as follows:

```
size_t length = get_length_from( f );
int (*m)[length] = malloc( sizeof *m * length ); // sizeof *m == sizeof (int [length])
```

`m` is a pointer to a `length`-element array of `int`, and we're allocating enough memory for `length` such arrays.  Assuming `length` is 3 again, you wind up with something that looks like this:

```
        +---+
m[0][0] |   |
        +---+ 
m[0][1] |   |
        +---+ 
m[0][2] |   |
        +---+ 
m[1][0] |   |
        +---+ 
m[1][1] |   |
        +---+ 
m[1][2] |   |
        +---+ 
m[2][0] |   |
        +---+ 
m[2][1] |   |
        +---+ 
m[2][2] |   |
        +---+
```

If VLAs are not available (versions earlier than C99, or C2011 where `__STDC_NO_VLA__` is defined) *and* you want all your array elements to be contiguous, then you'll have to allocate it as a 1D array:

```
size_t length = 3;
int *m = malloc( sizeof *m * length * length );
```

You can set up an additional array of pointers to *pretend* `m` is a 2D array:

```
int *q[] = { &m[0], &m[3], &m[6] };
```

So

```
q[0][0] == m[0];
q[0][1] == m[1];
q[0][2] == m[2];
q[1][0] == m[3];
q[1][1] == m[4];
...
```

etc.