# parameter passing / return of function arrays in C,

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, compiler-errors, parameter-passing

I'm having a problem with my schooljob where I have to do in C, which consists of, get the inverse array through the enclosed array. Every time I try to call a function that have a array as parameter, that error apear "Row 37 [Error] incompatible type for argument 2 of 'Invertible'".

So far this is what I could produce in C# and then I tried to rewrite it in C, but I'm not getting success because I do not know the language.

I'm using DEV C++ to compile my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int mult = 0;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
float detLaplace(int n, float a[n][n]);
float det2(float array[2][2]);
float det3(float array[3][3]);
float * cafactor(int n, float array[n][n], int Row,int Column);
float * matcafactor(int n, float a[n][n]){
float * Transpose(int n, float array[n][n]);
float * Adjugate  (int n, float array[n][n]);
float * Invertible (int n, float array[n][n]);

//MAIN #TODO
int * main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int l;
    int c;
    int o;
    float v;

    printf("Insert the array order: ");
    scanf("%d\n",&o);

    static float array[100][100];

    for(l=0;l<o;l++){
        for(c=0;c<o;c++){
            printf("\nInsert Cell value[%i][%i]: ",&l,&c);
            scanf("%d",&v);
        }
            printf("\n");
    }   

    array = Invertible (o,array[100][100]);

    int op = 0
    for(l=o;o>0;o--){
        op=op+(l*l);
    }

    printf("\nOperation numbers=%d |",&op);

    printf("\narray Invertible :\n |");

    for(l=0;l<o;l++){
        for(c=0;c<o;c++){
            printf("%d |",&array[l][c]);
        }
            printf("\n");
    }   

    return 0;
}





/*
    |-------------------|
    |   FUNCTIONS       |
    |-------------------|
*/

//LAPLACE
float detLaplace(int n, float a[n][n]){

    if(n == 1){
        // array 1x1
        return a[0][0];
    }
    else{
        float det = 0;
        int i, row, col, j_aux, i_aux;

        //Select first line to calculate the cofactors
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            //ignore the zeros (zero time anything equal zero)
            if (a[0][i] != 0) {
                float aux[n - 1][n - 1];
                i_aux = 0;
                j_aux = 0;
                //Generate the array to calculate the cofactors
                for(row = 1; row < n; row++){
                    for(col = 0; col < n; col++){
                        if(col != i){
                            aux[i_aux][j_aux] = a[row][col];
                            j_aux++;
                        }
                    }
                    i_aux++;
                    j_aux = 0;
                }
                float factor = (i % 2 == 0)? a[0][i] : -a[0][i];
                det = det + factor * detLaplace(n - 1, aux);
            }
        }
        return det;
    }
}

//Generate cofactor array
float * matcafactor(int n, float a[n][n]){
    static float matCof[n][n];
    float aux[n - 1][n - 1];    
    float det = 0;
    int i, row, col, j_aux, i_aux;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        i_aux = 0;
        j_aux = 0;
            //Generate the array to calculate the cofactors
        for(row = 1; row < n; row++){
            for(col = 0; col < n; col++){
                if(col != i){
                    aux[i_aux][j_aux] = a[row][col];
                    j_aux++;
                }
            }
            i_aux++;
            j_aux = 0;
        }
           float factor = (i % 2 == 0)? a[0][i] : -a[0][i];
           matCof[i][n] = factor * detLaplace(n - 1, aux);
    }
    //Return the cofactor array https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWQrcWYyqWK9wUGoUS9bnaGn5iCmj6CD9016BF0jopfcg4Xsme
    return matCof;
}

//Transpose the array
float * Transpose(int n, float array[n][n]){

    int Row=0;
    int Column=0;
    static float[n][n] matTramp;

    for(Row< D,Row++){
        for(Column< D,Column++){
            matTramp[Column,Row] = array[Row,Column];
        }
    }

    //Return the Transpose the array
    return matTramp;
}

float * Adjugate  (int n, float array[n][n]){
    static float matAux[n][n];

    matAux = matcafactor(n,array[n][n]);    
    matAux = Transpose(n,matAux[n][n]);

    //return the Transpose cafactors array 
    return matAux;
}

float * Invertible (int n, float array[n][n]){
    static float matAux[n][n];
    float detPrincipal=0;
    int i;
    int j;

    //Get the determinant of the main array detPrincipal= mainDertminant
    detPrincipal = detLaplace(n, array[n][n]);  

    matAux = Adjugate (n,array[n][n]);  

    for(i = 0, i<n,i++){
        for(j = 0, i<n,i++){
            matAux[n][n] = matAux[n][n]*(1/detPrincipal);
        }
    }

    return matAux;
}
```

Comment: remove the `[100][100]` after the identifier for the array - what you are doing with this line is indexing the *100th column of the 100th row of array*, thus you are passing an argument of type `float` to Invertible, who expects `float [][]` as the second argument - the line should look like this: `array = Invertible (o,array);`

Comment: Expressions line `return marAux;` are returning `float (*)[n]`, not `float *`. There is a difference, and being unfamiliar with that is related to the root problem you already identified ("don't know the language"). This can't possibly compile regardless, as the misplaced `{` after what should be the `matcafactor` prototype. Also, you can't have *static* variable length arrays in C, so that won't work either. In short, the problem are *numerous*, and there is no quick fix to this.

Comment: To add to what @WhozCraig accurately said, you're likely going to be best off passing the result array to the functions.  You can't pass `array` (of size 100x100) to functions that are told, for example, that the size is 4 and the array is supposed to be `array[n][n]` (where I hypothesize that `n == 4`).  You're brave if you actually type 10,000 numbers for a 100x100 array.  Also, you read the values into `v` (after misprinting by including the `&` in `&l` and `&c` in the call to `printf()`), and never set the array.   As was said, you have major surgery to do to create a compilable program.

Comment: You need to find a C text book and learn about how to handle matrices using C99 variable length arrays.  They're great, but you can't use them as shown.

Comment: `[Column,Row]` ==> `[Column][Row]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many errors in your program.

1. `int * main(int argc, char *argv[])` should be 
   `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

   Main should return integer not pointer to integer.
2. `printf("\nInsert Cell value[%i][%i]: ",&l,&c);` should be `printf("\nInsert Cell value[%i][%i]: ",l,c);`

   `l` and `c` are `int`'s. Therefore the printf should use the value directly.
3. `scanf("%d",&v);` should be `scanf("%f",&v);`

   `v` is a float. For float's you should use `%f` for `printf` and scanf`
4. `array = Invertible (o,array[100][100]);` to `Invertible (o,array);`

   You have two issues here.  Firstly, in the assignment you are using `array[100]100]`.  Secondly, You are assigning the result back to `array`.

   The type of `Invertible` is `float * Invertible (int n, float array[n][n]);` You cannot assign a `float` pointer to an array.
5. `int op = 0` --> Missing semicolon.
6. `printf("\nOperation numbers=%d |",&op);` and `printf("%d |",&array[l][c]);`
   Remove the & and use %f for the array.
7. `static float matCof[n][n];`  -> You need to decide the size of this array in advance.

There are many more errors, but you can get going with these.

You should compile your code with the `-Wall` option to get these errors.

Comment: Thanks I see some points,, but how I could create a dinamic array for my aplication if I need this to work for an array[100][100], array[9][9] or array[n][n]. I have no idea how I could correct the points 4 and 7.

Comment: For no 7. The fix is as shown.  For no 10. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970698/using-malloc-for-allocation-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-with-different-row-lengt

Comment: @Raphaeldemelo accept and upvote the answer if it helped you. That acknowledgement encourages people to contribute.